# how to use "navtive_type" in flatbuffers?

Tags: flatbuffers

here is my test schema:

```
native_include "mystruct.h"
table testdata
{
    data:mystruct (native_type);
}
```

the flatc shows: error: expecting: table instead got: identifier: native_include.

I can't find any detail informations about how to use native_type in the flatbuffers document.

please, can someone show me some examples how to use, and where should i write "namespace flatbuffers { FlatbufferStruct Pack(const native_type& obj); native_type UnPack(const FlatbufferStruct& obj); }"

thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`native_include` should be parsed, if it thinks it is an identifier, you may be using an older version of `flatc` ?

As for `native_type`, that is an attribute for the struct, not the field, e.g.: `struct mystruct (native_type: "mycpptype") { .. }` as shown in the documentation here: https://google.github.io/flatbuffers/flatbuffers_guide_use_cpp.html

Comment: Thanks! I checked the source file, it's a old version!

After sync the source code to the latest version, it works! Thanks again!

Comment: What had me struggling for a while is that the native_ commands only work if you have the --gen-object-api flag set.